# I want to fill a dictionary<string,int> with data from a txt file. The file contains names and numbers this way: Peter;123

Tags: c#

What i want to do is to use something like this Console.Writeline($"Name {Key} - Points: {Value}");
but i dont know how to make the data from the txt into Keys and  Values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, you want to fill a `Dictionary<string, int>` with the names and points of people, right?

If yes then I would suggest never use a dictionary Keys for names, because names are the data that can be duplicate which will eventually lead your software to throw exceptions regarding that.

Make a Generic List of custom class data. Something like this:

```
public class UserPoint
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

Then like below you can read your text file and load the data into the Generic List.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"myfile.txt"); // I assume each user info is separated by a newline.
    var pointsList = new List<UserPoint>();
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        var splittedLine = line.Split(';');
        if(splittedLine.Length < 1) continue;
        var userPoint = new UserPoint { Name = splittedLine[0].Trim() };

        if(splittedLine.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(splittedLine[1].Trim(), out var points)) // updated the direct conversion to safe conversion with tryparse.
        {
            userPoint.Points = points; // To get rid of extra parsing you can also keep Points property as string.
        }
        pointsList.Add(userPoint);
    }

}
```

PS: There are multiple other ways to read the text file but I used a simple way, You can also use `FileStream` and `StreamReader` classes if you like. Read more on reading text files on these [MSDN Articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file).

**EDIT:**
I notice you want to iterate and print through the list as well, you can do in the first loop or you can write a loop again. See:

```
foreach(var userPoint in pointsList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {userPoint.Name}, Points: {userPoint.Points}");
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
OP has asked to sort the list in descending order based on the points value. Here is a solution for that:

```
pointsList = pointsList.OrderByDescending(userPoint => userPoint.Points).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I finally did it! Or more like you did it. Thanks i spent the whole afternoon yesterday trying to make this work. Im not good at this but its finally finished.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I would like to ask 1 more thing. Where should i put OrderByDescending to make it still work? I realized just now that it needs to descend from highest points to lowest.

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out. Thank you again!

Comment: @user13631847, OrderByDescending is a method of Generic List element. Glad you figured it out, I will put it in my answer so it might help others as well.